# Using PyQGIS to transform layer of polygons into layer of holes inside bbox?

Tags: pyqgis, polygon

I'm using python in QGIS.
I have a layer of polygons (its a result of some earlier dissolving and has no overlapping polygons but some holes and islands in holes etc). I want to build a new layer which contains one polygon representing a bbox of the first layer with each polygon cut from it.

Essentially I want to "invert" the layer I have so that where the was polygon, now there is not, and where there was not polygon now there is. All inside a bounding box of the original layer.

I can build a bbox easily and I tried to "subtract" the polygon layer from my new bbox polygon layer but the process slows to a stop and then crashes my PC. Here's the algorythm

```
processing.runalg("qgis.difference","path/to/polygon.shp","path/to/bbox.shp","path/to/result.shp")
```

I dont care about attributes (obviously). I just need to cut one set of polygons from one larger polygon.

It seems so simple, I wish I could find a simple command or script to acheive this.
As stated at the top I'm looking for a solution in python in QGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so I wanted to convert islands to holes and holes into islands but couldn't find a command to do it in QGIS so I wrote a script myself.

Here is that "simple" script which will invert an input_layer into a bbox polygon in an output_layer. The whole process ran over a couple of seconds to invert a 25MB shape file. Better than crashing out with a call to "difference"!

```
output_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:"+str(input_layer.crs().authid().split(':')[1]), "output_layer", "memory")
output_layer_provider = output_layer.dataProvider()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(output_layer)

bbox_feature_list=[]
bbox_feature = QgsFeature()
bbox_feature_outer_rings =QgsGeometry.fromRect(input_layer.extent()).asPolygon()
bbox_feature_outer_ring=bbox_feature_outer_rings[0]
bbox_feature_list.append(bbox_feature_outer_ring)

island_rings=[]
polygon_geoms=[]
features = input_layer.getFeatures()
for f in features:
    geom = f.geometry()
    if geom.wkbType() == QGis.WKBPolygon:
        polygon_geoms.append(geom.asPolygon())
    if geom.wkbType() == QGis.WKBMultiPolygon:
        for polygon in geom.asMultiPolygon():
            polygon_geoms.append(polygon)       

for polygon_geom in polygon_geoms:
    ring_count=0
    for ring in polygon_geom:
        ring_count+=1
        if ring_count==1:
            bbox_feature_list.append(ring)
        else:
            island_rings.append(ring)

bbox_feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(bbox_feature_list))
(res, outFeats) = output_layer_provider.addFeatures([bbox_feature])

island_features=[]
for island_ring in island_rings:
    island_feature = QgsFeature()
    island_feature_list=([island_ring])
    island_feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(island_feature_list))
    island_features.append(island_feature)
(res, outFeats) = output_layer_provider.addFeatures(island_features)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(output_layer)
output_layer.updateExtents()
```

NOTE: After running this process I sometimes have to run the v.clean algorithm from GRASS with bpol tool in order to do spacial processes on it later. I'm not sure why, but this fixes it for me.